# Docker multistage on windows COPY c:\windows not allowed

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to install the vsbuildtools in a docker container for windows. Unfortunately, even with the installPath the installer installs stuff everywhere.

I, therefore, have to do

```
Step 27/32 : COPY --from=SetupPhase C:\Windows C:\Windows
```

but it gives me this error:

```
docker : COPY failed: copy from c:\ or c:\windows is not allowed on
windows At line:1 char:1
+ docker build -m 2GB -t monamimani/msbuild .
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (COPY failed: co...owed on windows:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   Command executed with exception: COPY failed: copy from c:\ or c:\windows is not allowed on windows
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround, where this doesn't work

```
COPY --from=SetupPhase ["C:\\Windows", "C:\\Windows"]
```

but this works

```
COPY --from=SetupPhase ["C:\\Windows\\assembly", "C:\\Windows\\assembly"]
```

So I just need to run a copy operation for each subfolder of c:\windows that I want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is a permission issue by trying another path, just for testing.

But do consider also "[Dockerfile on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile)", which specifies, for the `COPY` command:

> ### Windows Considerations
>
> **On Windows, the destination format must use forward slashes**.
>   For example, these are valid `COPY` instructions.
>
> ```
> COPY test1.txt /temp/
> COPY test1.txt c:/temp/
> ```
>
> However, the following will not work.
>
> ```
> COPY test1.txt c:\temp\
> ```

Comment: Hi, I tried it and it is not that. I believe it is a restriction from docker for windows but i didn't found any proof yet.

Comment: Probably linked to the notion of context: for testing, try and copy something to the current build folder, instead of c:\Windows.